# How to reuse the result of a previous computation without messing up autograd?

Tags: python, pytorch, autograd

I'm trying to train a model on sequences of data, where the current output depends on both the current input and the first output. My code looks something like this:

```
for i in range(time):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    if i == 0:
        first_output = model.output_init()  
    output = model(input,first_output)
    loss = F.loss(output)
    if i == 0:
        first_output = output
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

When I try to run it, it gives an error: "Trying to backward through the graph a second time ". If I understand it correctly, it seems like "previous_output" is still being used by autograd on subsequent steps, when I really want it to be considered as a fixed input. I've tried using `output.detach().clone()` (doesn't work) and `output.requires_grad = False` (raises an error that I can't change the grad flag for a non-leaf variable). Any ideas on how to get around this?

Comment: If you want to BP through time, why not sum up the whole loss across the sequence and make a single BP step rather than BP every time step?

Comment: Please, elaborate on how "`output.detach().clone()` (doesn't work)". It should.

Comment: Haha, summing the loss before BP works, can't believe I didn't think of that. Thanks!

As for `output.detach().clone()` not working, it would give the same error message of "Trying to backward through the graph ....". Not sure why it doesn't work.